# Are these Python expressions equivalent to each other?

Tags: python, ternary-operator, equivalent

Given the following Python function (ignoring its shortcomings):

```
def adjust_year(year):
  return year > 2000 and year - 2000 or year - 1900
```

If I change it to instead be:

```
def adjust_year(year):
  return year - 2000 if year > 2000 else year - 1900
```

Will the behavior be equivalent or have I changed it in some subtle way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are indeed equivalent, but the conditional expression variation is preferred.

Your expression narrowly avoids the typical `and ... or` pitfall where the middle expression evaluates to a falsy value (`year >= 2000 and year - 2000 or year - 1900` and `year = 2000` will result in `100`).

Comment: Which one is the 'conditional expression' variant, the second using ternary operator?

Comment: @WilliamKF: *any* operator that takes three operands can be called a ternary operator. :-) It's officially called a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), but yes, that's the one I meant.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to tackle this. One is to logically analyse both versions; the other is to use brute force and compare the results for every valid input:

```
def adjust_year_1(year):
  return year > 2000 and year - 2000 or year - 1900

def adjust_year_2(year):
  return year - 2000 if year > 2000 else year - 1900

for y in range(-4000, 4000):
  if adjust_year_1(y) != adjust_year_2(y):
    print y, adjust_year_1(y), adjust_year_2(y)
```

This doesn't print anything, demonstrating that the functions are indeed equivalent for years between -4000 and 4000 (it's easy to see that they are also equivalent for inputs outside this range).

Comment: ROFL. Upvoted your answer for an unusual approach it demonstrates. Really enjoyed it.